# Fallback for display flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I give the same spacing to the boxes I have instead of having them all together with so much space on the right?

I normally use display flex cause it does that quite easily but since not all browsers support flex property I am trying another way around.

Below is my code and I hope you can help.

```css
.main > div{
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
.yellow{
  background: yellow;
}
.red{
  background: red;
}
.green{
  background: green;
}
.black{
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="red">
    
  </div>
  <div class="green">
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="yellow">
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="black">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Depending on what your building, supporting and target audience is, support fot flexbox is pretty good: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox. Is there any issue you have with flexbox an certain platforms?

Comment: +1 what is your support: IE10+ and Android4.4+? Fine, browserslist+Autoprefixer and your job is done! :) Otherwise please add your original caseS (with `@supports (display: flex)` maybe) so we can better answer you. Multiline flex hasn't the same fallbacks as monoline for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```css
.main {
  text-align: justify;
}

.main:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

div>div {
  display: inline-block;
  /* height, width and border for demo purpose only */
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border: thin solid darkgray;
}


/* for browsers that support flex */

@supports (display:flex) {
  .main {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .main:after {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that `supports` is not supported by IE although IE10+ supports flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many blocks you have you could use percentages:

```
.main > div {
  width: 25%;
}
```

Otherwise you might use a table:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="background:red;"></td>
    <td style="background:green;"></td>
    <td style="background:black;"></td>
    <td style="background:blue;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>BUG-17</title>
        <style>
        
        .main > div
        {
        display: inline-flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content:space-between;
        height: 200px;
        width: 333px;
        }
        .yellow
        {
        background: yellow;
        display:flex;

        }
        .red{
        background: red;
        display:flex;
        }
        .green{
        background: green;
        display:flex;
        }
        .black{
        background: black;
        display:flex;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="red">
                 
            </div>
            <div class="green">
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="yellow">
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="black">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are good to work on responsive design.